# What's the difference between 'teacher of English' and 'English teacher'

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Is *teacher of English* the same as *English teacher* and if not, what is the difference between?

> I am an *English teacher*.

> I am a *teacher of English*.

Comment: English teacher- a teacher whose nationality is England(Britain).       but a teacher of English is literally what it is saying -a teacher of English language.

Comment: @ram "A teacher who is English by nationality" is one possible meaning, so in those casese where there is potential for ambiguity, "teacher of English" should always be used. But where there is no potential of ambiguity, "teacher of English" can be easily attributized to "an English teacher"

Answer (score 2):

They are virtually the same, "a teacher of English" is more formal; "an English teacher" or "our English teacher" a bit shortened and used where a phrase "X **of** something" would complicate the syntax of the sentence.

However, if you are introducing yourself, I'd say it's best to use "I am a teacher of English" as a more formal, substantial phrase.

But "an English teacher" is totally correct, too. [See it used in a book by two Brits.](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=8HHeCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT163&lpg=PT163&dq=%22our+English+teacher+gave+us%22&source=bl&ots=s3saxSNjwl&sig=LWFHM2Q0Z2hIpvGeTIVCfmFwwQE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8g--npv3YAhUCVywKHRt3A_8Q6AEIVjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22our%20English%20teacher%20gave%20us%22&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

**'English'** is a word used both for the language and the nationality (of people who hail from England). So, when we say **"I am an English teacher.",** People may take the speaker as a teacher who lives in England. When we phrase it like - **"I am a teacher or English language."**, it becomes pretty much clear. Well, these days, both the notions are in play so you can use any of them.

Answer (score 0):

English teacher depicts any teacher whose nationality is England, but teacher of English language refers to any one whose profession is to teach English language. Let us go with this to avoid the ambiguity since we have teachers from other countries also in the profession of teaching English language.

Comment: While that might be good advice, it is not a convention generally adopted. "English teacher" can also mean a teacher of English, much like "biology teacher" means a teacher of biology.