# a French translator

Tags: meaning, adjectives

a. He is a French translator.

I think that sentence means that he is French and he is a translator.
We don't know what language or languages he translates from and what language or languages he translates into.

Could (a) have any other meanings?

Comment: Yes. It is possibly ambiguous and the meaning could depend on context, but personally I would only say it like that if he did translations in and out of French. If I was in the business of providing translation services and a client needed help with Chinese, I might say something like "Ah I know a French guy, who works as a Chinese translator".

Comment: As an actual translator, I never say the languages I work from with only one adjective, which would be ambiguous. I use:  I am a French>English translator or French-to-English translator. For example.

Comment: The most famous example is probably "a French teacher" - a teacher from France or a teacher of French? Google show several pages discussing this.

Comment: @StuartF If you are in the States and say that a person is a French teacher, you can be pretty sure they are referring to the language and not the nationality. Anyway, as I said, for translators, there need not be that issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between 'teacher of English' and 'English teacher'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/155164/whats-the-difference-between-teacher-of-english-and-english-teacher) Same basic issue: *Does **English / French / German / ...** refer to the language or the nationality?*

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a question about learning English, as I imagine this statement would carry the same kind of ambiguity in many languages.

Yes, it could mean two things. Just look at the Wikipedia entry for most notable people and you'll see it normally states their nationality and occupation, for example "*an English author*" or "*a Canadian film star*". So, someone who is French by nationality and works as a translator might be referred to as "*a French translator*". And if such a person speaks several languages, then maybe their work involves translating to and from languages other than their own native language, meaning they are a French translator, but not a translator of French.

As with all so-called 'ambiguous' statements, context is the key. Aside from the example I gave above, it would be a convoluted scenario in which a person was described as 'a French translator' and it not mean that their work involves the French language.

Comment: So, I am an American translator? That would only refer to my nationality. I am an American translator with these languages pairs: French>English and Spanish>English. He's a French translator working from to Chinese to French.

Comment: @Lambie Like I said, context. American isn't a language. As I already stated, it would be a convoluted situation where you introduced yourself as 'an American translator', but I'd have to assume you were an American that translates. On the other hand, if someone introduced themselves as a 'sign language interpreter', there is only one way that could be understood.

Comment: @Astralbee Don't be so sure. When I worked for the UK subsidiary of an American group,  we found some of our reports needed "translating into American", for there to be any chance of them being understood.  And vice-versa. But they never seemed to like it when we asked them to translate things into English. Two nations separated by a common language. 

Comment: No the statement would not carry the same ambiguity in "just about any language". In Welsh, _Cymraeg_ pertains to the Welsh language, and if used of a person would mean "Welsh-speaking" as opposed to _Cymreig_, which refers to nationality. In Georgian,  the distinction between  ქართველი  _kartveli_ (Georgian, applied to people) and ქართული _kartuli_ Georgian, non-people, including language) is regular for national and similar adjectives.

Comment: @ColinFine One language down, 7098 to go.

Comment: @WS2 What you have there is an example of how flexible the word 'translate' is, not evidence that American is a language. It is a dialect of English. Dialects are a subgroup of languages. I fully expect some on this site will argue the point, but it comes down to this - if you can speak and understand BrEng, AmEng and AusEng, are you *trilingual*? Of course not. Incidentally, BrEng speakers have been watching Hollywood movies for nearly 100 years without the need for so-called 'translation'.

Comment: @Astralbee As I guess Americans have been reading the Bible for 300 years without the need for a translation. into American. Nonetheless the first time an American told me he had just "gassed the car", and when asked in a hotel in Orlando if I wanted my eggs "up, down, easy, or dropped?" - I did wonder how I might converse without the aid of a dictionary!

Comment: @ws2 Well, they aren't reading it in the original languages. I imagine you're referring to the King James version, which is the 2nd most popular Bible translation in the USA. That's written in early modern English which most present-day British English speakers have difficulty with, too. The top translation in the USA is the New International Version, which came out over 40 years ago and is in American English being the work of a US-founded and based committee.

Comment: @Astralbee The James I version(1611 )- is roughly contemporaneous with Shakespeare. Indeed the English of each, as works of poetry, stands  head and shoulders above anything more recent. As far as I know they haven't produced an American version of Hamlet, so why the Bible? Having said that, a historian speaking on the subject in 2011 at a lecture I attended, left us in no doubt about the early-seventeenth-century political influence over the text - all those righteous kings in the OT - none of whom is a tyrant. The message - trust in the regal throne of the Stuarts.

Comment: Has the NIV found any biblical kings like George III?

Comment: @WS2 I don't know where you are going with that last comment. I didn't intend to initiate a discussion about the integrity of biblical kings. I was just challenging your statement that Americans read the Bible in something other than modern, American English, which they don't unless they choose to, as well as pointing out that the archaic language of the older translation poses just as much of an issue to speakers of other English dialects.

Answer (score 2):

It is ambiguous.

It would be valid to say "I'm a Scottish translator."  (While there is a language "Scots", there is no language called "Scottish")  and so this unambiguously means "A person from Scotland who translates"

You could also say "I'm a Gaelic translator".  There is a language called "Gaelic" spoken in parts of Scotland (it's closely related to Irish), but there is no nationality "Gaelic".  That would unambiguously mean a person who translates to or from Gaelic. Without other context you'd assume that they probably translate from English, as English is the majority language in Scotland.

But using "French translator" is simply unclear.  It would seem a little odd to tell people your nationality and not the language. It would seem a little odd not to mention the language pair, not even by implication.  It is easily and naturally avoided:  "I'm a Chinese-to-French translator" gives the language pair.  "I'm French and a translator of Chinese" gives the nationality with no ambiguity and implies that the person translates Chinese into French.